# How do you check if your phone has IR blaster?

Tags: hardware, remote-control

I downloaded some apps from the Play Store for controlling my TV using my phone. One of the requirements for it to work is that your phone must have an IR blaster in it. How do I check if my phone has an IR blaster?

Comment: Generally you can just look at it - they're usually not hard to spot. Alternatively, have you looked up your phone's specifications online?

Comment: What is your phone model?

Comment: If your phone has a hardware IR blaster, then it would be quite unusual if you don't have a built in application that uses the IR blaster. It's unlikely that the manufacturer would bother installing a unique hardware like IR that can't be used with the built in application (these kind of unusual hardwares are generally touted as selling points).

Answer (score 2):

You can check if your phone has it on [Smartphones with IR blasters (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_with_an_IR_blaster#Smartphones)

**Note**: the list may not be exhaustive.

> 2013
>
> - HTC One
> - HTC One Max
> - LG G2
> - LG G Flex
> - LG G Pro Lite
> - LG Optimus F6
> - LG Optimus G Pro
> - LG Optimus L9 II
> - Samsung Galaxy Note 3
> - Samsung Galaxy S4
> - Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini
> - Samsung Galaxy Mega
> - Sony Xperia Z (Japanese version only)
> - Sony Xperia Z1 (Japanese version only)
> - Sony Xperia ZL (Discontinued)
> - Samsung Galaxy J
> - ZTE Nubia Z5S
>
> 2014
>
> - HTC One (M8)
> - Huawei Honor 6
> - Huawei Honor 6 Plus
> - LG G Pro 2
> - LG G2 Mini
> - LG G3
> - LG G3 S (Vigor)
> - LG L90
> - LG G Vista
> - LG Volt
> - Samsung ATIV SE
> - Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo
> - Samsung Galaxy Note 4
> - Samsung Galaxy Note Edge
> - Samsung Galaxy S5 Active
> - Samsung Galaxy S5 Duos
> - Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini
> - Xiaomi Mi 4
> - ZTE Grand Memo II LTE
> - ZTE Grand X Max
> - ZTE Nubia X6
> - ZTE Nubia Z7
> - ZTE Nubia Z7 Max
>
> 2015
>
> - HTC One (M9)
> - HTC One M9+
> - LG G4
> - LG G Flex 2
> - Oppo Mirror 3
> - Samsung Galaxy S6
> - Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge
> - Samsung Galaxy S6 Active
> - Xiaomi RedMi Note 2
> - ZTE Grand X Max+
> - ZTE Nubia Z9
> - Samsung Galaxy A8 Duos

Comment: I'd never trust a list to be complete :) But yes, if it's on that list, it will have it. If it's not on the list, you need to search further :)